# Functions whose codomain's form depends from the element taken from the domain

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, article-writing

As in the title, I have a notational problem regarding functions whose codomain directly depends on the elements taken from the domain.

Here there is an example.

Let $X$ be a set with $x \in X$. Let $Y$ be another set and put a correspondence between $X$ and $Y$ such that for every $x \in X$ there is at least one $y \in Y$. Let $Y(x)$ denote the set of those elements of $Y$ that are in correspondence with $x$.

Now, imagine that we want to set a function $f$ that for every $x \in X$ gives an element in the set of probability distributions over $Y(x)$.
**How do we write this function?**

An option is of course
$$ f : X \to \Delta ( Y(x) ), $$
but in my opinion this is not completely correct, because of the $x$ that pops up in the codomain that does depend from the element we choose from the domain, without making explicit this relation.

Another option is to write that there is a function $f$ such that $x \mapsto \Delta ( Y(x) )$.

What is the correct one?
Is there any other option?

Thanks in advance for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were going to be talking about only one such function, I’d probably just say something like this:

> Let $f:X\to\bigcup_{x\in X}\Delta\big(Y(x)\big)$ be such that $f(x)\in\Delta\big(Y(x)\big)$ for each $x\in $X$.

If I were going to be talking about several such functions, I’d define the set of them:

> Let $$D=\bigcup_{x\in X}\Delta\big(Y(x)\big)\;,$$ and let $$\mathscr{F}=\left\{f\in{}^XD:f(x)\in\Delta\big(Y(x)\big)\text{ for each }x\in X\right\}\;.$$

(I use the notation ${}^AB$ for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$; you can substitute whatever other notation you prefer.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote a set, and $Y$ denote a function that accepts an element $x \in X$ and returns a set $Y(x).$ Then the set of all functions that accept an element $x \in X$ and return an element of $Y(x)$ is denoted $\prod_{x \in X}Y(x)$. So

$$f \in \prod_{x \in X}\Delta(Y(x))$$

is the notation you're looking for.

Comment: Actually I am not looking for a way to denote the set whose $f$ is an element. I was looking for a way to properly define $f$. Moreover I do not think that your formula capture what I mean. Indeed, in your case $f$ looks like a vector indexed by $x \in X$.

Comment: @Kolmin, sorry I misunderstood what you were trying to do. The edit gives the correct notation (assuming that, in general, $\Delta(Y)$ denotes the set of probability distributions over $Y$. I am not a probabilist, unfortunately.) And yes, a function *is* just like a vector indexed by $X$! For example, a vector of real numbers $x=(a,b,c)$ can be identified with the function $x:\{0,1,2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $x(0)=a$, $x(1)=b$, $x(2)=c$. Or alternatively, $x_0 = a$, $x_1=b$, $x_2=c$. You may prefer to begin numbering at $1$, of course.

Comment: I think I kind of see what you mean, but still I thinks it does not really make the job again. To me, $f$ should really look like an element of the set that Brian M. Scott wrote down.

Comment: @Kolmin, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_products) if you're not convinced. Notice their definition of $\prod$ looks similar to what Brian wrote. I can understand if you find Brian's way of writing it easier to read, though, since it actually looks like $f$ is a function.

Comment: Actually I knew you were referring to that, but I also think that strictly speaking it is a bit of an indirect way to define $f$, while I was looking for something more direct, as in the OQ. Btw, even if apparently the question was not particularly interesting for a large audience, I think that in the end your answer as well can be a nice reference point, at least to exploit the inner structure of the $f$ function we are looking at.